# How to create a procedure to send email using a gxflow template with a batch (script) task?

Tags: genexus

We have a batch (script) task in a workflow to remind an approver about pending requests.
These reminders need to reach the approver by email, in a similar format to when they receive them the first time.

We don't want to generate a user task or a new task in the GxFlow Client user inbox. Only to send reminders by email.
Could we use a procedure that invokes the email sending service using a GxFlow notification template?
What would the code for that procedure be like?
What another alternative can we use?
[gxflow](/questions/tagged/gxflow)
Genexus 18 U8
Web .NET

[image]